# How to bind data to Kendo UI in server side

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I'm using Kendo UI in my ASP.Net webforms. 
Is there any way to bind data to Kendo UI controls in server side, since the client side binding costs the performance speed.

Answer (score 1):

I guess the component you are trying to bind is a grid. Here is one snippet I use. Feel free to activate and deactivate options. Please see the examples at https://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/grid/serverbinding

```
@model IEnumerable<yourProject.Models.modelName>

@(Html.Kendo().Grid(Model)    
    .Name("Grid")
    .Columns(columns => {
        columns.Bound(p => p.col1).Groupable(false);
        columns.Bound(p => p.col2);
        columns.Bound(p => p.col3);
        columns.Bound(p => p.col4);
    })
    .Pageable()
    .Sortable()
    .Scrollable() 
    .Filterable()
    .Groupable()
)
```